# Resources and references about phase kickback trick

Tags: resource-request, phase-kickback

I am writing a piece of work on Grover's algorithm and I am looking for references on the phase-kickback trick to transform a state oracle in a phase oracle.

Is there any paper or there a part on it in Nielsen and Chuang ?

Comment: The phase kickback trick transforms a state oracle to a phase oracle, not vice versa!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [IBM Qiskit text](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-gates/phase-kickback.html) has a section on this that you may find useful.

For something more "academic" [Mermin](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Quantum_Computer_Science/q2S9APxFdUQC?hl=en&gbpv=0) Sections 4.2-4.5, [Schuld and Petruccione](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Supervised_Learning_with_Quantum_Compute/1zpsDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) Sections 3.5.1-3.5.3, or [Nielson and Chuang](https://books.google.com/books/about/Quantum_Computation_and_Quantum_Informat.html?id=65FqEKQOfP8C) Sections 6.1-6.2 may have what you're looking for.

Schuld and Petruccione also have references at the end of each chapter, which could be worth looking into.

Comment: Ok, thanks ! I wanted to know if there was anything a bit more "academic"

Comment: Got it, I just added a bit to my answer. I haven't read these sections myself in a while, so can't say for sure if they contain what you're looking for. But if these books covered phase-kickback in any detail, the above is where it would be.

Comment: An update to the link, since I was looking for something similar and the former is not working: https://learn.qiskit.org/course/ch-gates/phase-kickback